# Chrome driver: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, testing

Method getHomePageTest() fails with exception:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null`

Chrome: Version 121.0.6167.184 (Official Build) (64-bit)

chrome driver downloaded from: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/121.0.6167.184/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip

Test classes:

```
public class HomePage {

    private WebDriver driver;

    private static String PAGE_URL="https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/";

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using="ui-id-6")
    private WebElement gearItem;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
        this.driver.get(PAGE_URL);

        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
    }

    public void clickOnGearItem(){
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(gearItem)).click();
    }
}
```

TestBase:

```
public class TestBase {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void initializeWebDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chrome");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

ApplyTests:

```
public class ApplyTests extends TestBase {
    @Test
    public void getHomePageTest(){
        HomePage home = new HomePage(driver);
        home.clickOnGearItem();
    }
}
```

I tried using Selenium both with Mozilla and gecko-driver, and with Chrome and chrome-driver. I tested several versions, as advised, and checked to see if any of the existing StackOverflow questions answers this problem. However, the exception persists.
I have already updated the system and the browsers.
Running the code on Windows computer works, however, I need to be able to run it on Linux. Any helpful insight is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are you sure that Chrome (the browser) is installed on the Linux machine you're trying to run your code on?

Comment: It is installed :)

Comment: Do you see the browser being launched as part of the `initializeWebDriver` method?

Comment: I would check `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chrome")` the path you're specifying here, maybe try running your tests with `sudo`. Just speculations though.

Comment: @supputuri The browser doesn't launch.

Comment: @itishrishikesh still nothing

Comment: If browser doesn't launch, your instance is not created. Please check if chromedriver path and chrome installed properly on the machine.

Comment: @supputuri Thank you for suggestion, that was one of the first things I checked, but to no avail. Both path and driver are correct, along with chrome installation